# Rails print whitespace from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, whitespace

I'd like to debug a variable `@num` in my Rails controller, so I'm evaluating

```
<%= @num %>
```

in my Rails view. However, I cannot distinguish between `@num` being `'', ' '`, and `'  '` (and other different types of whitespace) when it's printed in the HTML. Is there any way to print it out clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be really sure:

```
<%= @num.inspect %>
```

When `@num = ' '` this should render:

```
" "
```

`#inspect` is great when you want to a representation of some object as a string.

If this is a complex object or large array or deep hash, I often prefer `#to_yaml` for inspection which lays it out in a somewhat readable format.

```
# controller
@foo = {:a => [:bar, :baz], :b => 123, :c => 'omg'}

# view
<pre><%= @foo.to_yaml %></pre>

# visible output
--- 
:b: 123
:c: omg
:a: 
- :bar
- :baz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%=debug @num %>
```

Will format it in haml.

```
<%= @num.inspect %>
```

Will format it as "p" does.

See [Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) (rails guides)